# iPhone app in the "iPad only" section of App Store

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

Is there any way to make iPhone app appear in the "iPad only" section of App Store?
The problem is: many of the users do not search in the "iPhone only" section and we can't currently make a universal app (or a separate app for iPad).

[image: iPad's App Store]

Comment: Of course I don't search `iPhone only` section. Not a big fan of running iPhone apps on iPad.

Answer (score 9):

No, of course you can't. That's why it's the iPad only section.

If you want iPad customers, make an iPad app. Phone apps running on the iPad are not a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Make a universal setting app for iPhone and iPad. And you should make UI in your app to fit both iPhone and iPad.